# Position absolute in position relative with fabricjs

Tags: html, css, fabricjs

I have this http://jsfiddle.net/116ea4wx/ , I want to div `#areaEditor` in front of div `.dcEditor` when I zoom to 1.5 scale.

```
<div id="areaEditor">
  <div class="dcEditor" id="idEditor">
       <canvas id="cEditor"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>


#areaEditor {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.dcEditor {
    width: 332.64px;
    height: 200.34px;
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background:#222;
}
#cEditor {
    width: 332.64px;
    height: 200.34px;
}
```

I have try with `z-index:-2;` on absolute to `.dcEditor`, but background on div `.dcEditor` still visible and text on canvas can't selection.

Comment: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/116ea4wx/1/) like this

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes : I can't  select of text on canvas

Comment: I got it, just add `overflow:hidden;` to `#areaEditor` and without `z-index` it's works